# Microsoft JScript runtime error using window.location in IE8

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer-8, javascript, window.location

I'm having a weird error in my code.
I'm getting an error:
Microsoft JScript runtime error: object doesn't support this action.
I'm using fullcalendar and on an event click I want to open the even details in the same window.  Oddly enough, this works fine in Chrome.  I also want to note that on an XP system it works fine both in IE8 and Chrome, while in Windows 7 chrome works fine and IE8 gives the error.

Here is a screen shot:
[image]

Here is my view code:

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/HomePagesMaster.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<Perspectiva.Models.EventViewModel>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    פרספקטיבה - לוח ארועים
</asp:Content>


<asp:Content ID="mainContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="PageContent" runat="server">
<!-- jquery scripts needed for for the calendar and datepicker -->
    <script src="<%=Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<%=Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.min.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<%=Url.Content("~/Scripts/fullcalendar.min.js")%>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="<%= Url.Content("~/Content/jquery-ui.custom.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="<%= Url.Content("~/Content/fullcalendar.css") %>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#calendar").fullCalendar({
                theme: true,
                header: {
                    left: 'month, agendaWeek, agendaDay',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'next,prev'
                },
                buttonIcons: {

                    next: 'circle-triangle-w',
                    prev: 'circle-triangle-e'
                },
                monthNames: ['ינואר', 'פברואר', 'מרץ', 'אפריל', 'מאי', 'יוני',
                            'יולי', 'אוגוסט', 'ספטמבר', 'אוקטובר', 'דצמבר'],
                monthNamesShort: ['ינו', 'פבר', 'מרץ', 'אפר', 'מאי', 'יונ',
                                 'יול', 'אוג', 'ספט', 'אוק', 'דצמ'],
                dayNames: ['ראשון', 'שני', 'שלישי', 'רביעי', 'חמישי', 'שישי', 'שבת'],
                dayNamesShort: ['א', 'ב', 'ג', 'ד', 'ה', 'ו', 'ש'],
                weekend: false,
                aspectRatio: 2,
                defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
                isRTL: true,
                axisFormat: 'HH:mm',
                minTime: '6:00',
                maxTime: '21:00',
                events: "/Scheduler/EventData/",
                allDaySlot: false,
                eventClick: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
                    window.location(event.url);
                }
            });
        });  
</script>

    <br />
    <div style="padding-bottom: 10px; text-align: center; font-size:xx-large; font-family: David;">לוח ארועים</div>

    <div id="calendar" style="font-size: medium"></div>
    <% if (Roles.IsUserInRole("manager"))
       { %>
            <div id="side" style="font-size:large; text-align: center; text-decoration: none;">               
                    <br />
                   <%= Html.ActionLink("הוסף ארוע חדש", "CreateEvent", "Scheduler") %>                
            </div>
    <% } %>
</asp:Content>
```

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you just need to need to change

window.location(event.url);

to

window.location = event.url;

I realize this post was created a while back, but I figured I would post the answer for anyone looking.